# t statistic formula

Tags: statistics

I just have a quick question about t statistic. Of these two, which formula is correct?

$$t(x) = \frac{\bar{X} - \mu }{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum \left ( X_{i} - \bar{X}\right )^{2}}}\sqrt{n-1}$$

$$t(x) = \frac{\bar{X} - \mu }{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum \left ( X_{i} - \bar{X}\right )^{2}}}\sqrt{n}$$

I came across both in different places (even within the same textbook) so don't know which one is correct. Thanks for helping!

Comment: They are equal.

Comment: How so? Sorry if this is too obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are mathematically equivalent, because $$\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{1/n}} = \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n-1} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{1/(n-1)}}.$$

That said, the second formula is a better reflection of how the $t$ statistic is calculated, because it is obtained by estimating the standard deviation of the population from the sample when it is unknown.  Thus, $$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$$ is the unbiased estimator for the variance $\sigma^2$ when $X_i$ are iid normal random variables with unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown variance $\sigma^2$.  Then the statistic $$\frac{X-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$$ is Student $t$ distributed where $s/\sqrt{n}$ is the standard error of the mean.